# Web3 js 1.0 is throwing big number error while transfering tokens

Tags: web3js, erc-20, ethereumjs

When I tried to transfer more then 1000 tokens, it's throwing an error like as mentioned below (I'm using web3 js 1.0.0 34 beta version).

> Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number 1e+23 to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "1e+23

Find code examples which I tried.

```
//var tokens = amount * 1e18;
//var tokens = amount * (10 ** 18);
//var tokens = parseInt(amount) * 1e18;
//var tokens = web3.utils.toBN(amount);
//var tokens = amount * Math.pow(10, decimal)
var tokens = web3.utils.toBN(amount * 1e18) ;
```

Does anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Web3.js and your token is using the standard 10<sup>18</sup> decimal, then you can also use [`web3.utils.toWei()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei) and [`web3.utils.fromWei()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei) to get to and from the big numbers you want pretty easy.

In this situation you can try this:

```
var amount = 1000
var tokens = web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether')
```

> "1000000000000000000000"

You can then easily convert that to a BN:

```
var bntokens = web3.utils.toBN(tokens)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. when i try the above code. im getting following error.  
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors.                                                                

code:
        var amount="10000000";

        var token = SmartContractHelper.web3Provider.utils.toWei(parseInt(amount), 'ether');

        var tokens = SmartContractHelper.web3Provider.utils.toBN(token)

Comment: when i hardcoded the token amount, its working fine. when i pass it from the variable, its not working.. is anything am i missing?

Comment: Check out my edit. Basically you need to use numbers represented as strings.

Comment: I am glad it worked out. Feel free to mark this answer as correct so the question is correctly indexed as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
import { BigNumber} from 'ethers';

....

const decimals = 18;
const trans_amount = 1500;
const amount= BigNumber.from(trans_amount).mul(BigNumber.from(10).pow(decimals));

consoel.og("amount is ", amount);
</pre>
```